# The UVa 3n + 1 in C++ with Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm

So, there are ways to do this, and/or optimize this. Stupid that I am, I immediately wants to implement a recursive function, which later caused a segmentation fault, and then I tried to adopt dynamic programming, and it seemed to work, but somehow I got Wrong answer.

Problem [Here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36)

So here's my code, and I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int cycleLength(long long int);

int cycleLengthResult[1000000];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, cur = 0, max = 0;
    while ( cin >> i >> j )
    {
        if ( i > j ) //swap to ensure i <= j
        {
            int s = i;
            i = j;
            j = s;
        }
        for ( int k = i ; k <= j ; ++ k )
        {
            cur = cycleLength(k);
            if (cur > max) max = cur;
        }
        cout << i << " " << j << " " << max << endl;
        max = 0;
    }
}

int cycleLength(long long int arg)
{
    if ( arg > 1000000 ) //if out of array bound, then don't memorize, just calculate
    {
        if (arg % 2 == 0)
        {
            return 1 + cycleLength(arg/2);
        }
        else
        {
            return 1 + cycleLength(arg*3+1);
        }
    }
    if (!cycleLengthResult[arg-1]) //if result for arg doesn't exist then....
    {
        int valueForArg = 0;
        if (arg == 1)
        {
            valueForArg = 1;
        }
        else if (arg % 2 == 0)
        {
            valueForArg = 1 + cycleLength(arg/2);
        }
        else
        {
            valueForArg = 1 + cycleLength(arg*3+1);
        }
        cycleLengthResult[arg-1] = valueForArg;
    }
    return cycleLengthResult[arg-1];
}
```

I passed all the sample inputs, and also (1, 1000000) for speed test. But it seemed that it's not the problem.

I want to fix my code, and not change the methodology used, of course, I can just not use recursive, and use a loop instead in main, which wouldn't overflow. But it's fun.

Comment: It be great if you comment code about the logic of your program so you can look back on it when an error arises or have the code more "readable". Often times it's just a simple logic error that's hidden somewhere in the program.

Comment: You are testing for `cycleLengthResult[arg-1]`, but where do you initialize the array (to all zeros)? Perhaps you should use `int cycleLengthResult[1000000] = {0};`

Comment: @Need4Sleep You are right, I will try to comment maybe next morning. It's 3 am here. I tried to add some comment, but I don't think they really explain things a lot clearer for people. And I took note along writing these code. They are meant for lecture, but I think it will become a especially sad lecture. LOL

Comment: @svetianov Ne I don't need to initialize them here, they are declared global, which mean they are initialized to 0 by default. I've tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the statement carefully:

**The integers i and j must appear in the output in the same order in which they appeared in the input**

So save them after reading and print the saved values.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right, that is the only error. Thanks a lot! I got an "Accepted" immediately!

Comment: @ShaneHsu: yep I got Accepted too before posting the answer :)